# Extracting slopes from several regression models using dplyr

Tags: dplyr, lm, coefficients

I would like to fit multiple models for each individual and each drug (both are the factor variable) using dplyr, I'm getting an error, and I'm not quite sure what's wrong. I want to extract the slope of each model to compute the average slope of the pairwise relationship of fitted model between individuals.

```
df.dr <- data.frame(
drug = factor(rep(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5), 4)), 
individual = factor(rep(letters[1:4], each = 20)),
dose = rep(c(10,5,1,0.5,0.1), times = 16),
viability = runif(80, min = 50, max = 200))

dfDrugInd = df.dr %>% group_by(drug, individual) %>%
  do(fitAll = lm(viability ~ ., data = .))

dfDrugIndSlope = tidy(dfDrugInd, fitAll)$estimate[2,1]

mean(dfDrugIndSlope)
```

Comment: there are several problems in your code, for example, there is an extract `)` in line 4.  Set aside the code first, if I understand your question correctly, you are actually asking for a `mixed-effect model` to achieve what you want, is it correct?  Using `group_by` and pipe logic does not work here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fixed the problem. I have several variables, and I want to compute all pairwise combinations of these variables in separate lm models. Then I want to extract the slope of each one and calculate the average of slopes for each variable. Here variables are individuals. I want to do this task for all drugs separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not fully understand why you need to perform regression analysis in this way (one by one, then average the coefficient), the following code should meet your needs:

But your question seemingly likes a `mixed-effect` model, which you may want to use the `lm4` package to achieve your results.

```
df.dr <- data.frame(
  drug = factor(rep(rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 5), 4)), 
  individual = factor(rep(letters[1:4], each = 20)),
  dose = rep(c(10,5,1,0.5,0.1), times = 16),
  viability = runif(80, min = 50, max = 200))

# split the dataset by group
df.sp <- split(df.dr, df.dr$drug)

# run separate `lm` on each group and store the results in a list
r <- lapply(df.sp, function(x) do.call("lm", list(viability ~ individual + dose, x)))

# extract the coefficient of target variable, say `individualc`
indi.cof <- sapply(r, function(x)x$coefficients[["individualc"]])

# get the mean
mean(indi.cof)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. I think that is the solution, but I will also check lm4.

Comment: @MohieddinJafari if you think the answer meets your needs, please accept it by clicking the green check mark on the left. Thanks!